# SQL multiple insert with sleep

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to insert multiple data with delay kind of thing/sleep for a few second?
for example here, Im going to insert the values (1,2) into my user table. Then after 5 seconds, it will proceed to insert value (3,4) into the same table, wait for 5 seconds and finally insert (5,6) into the table.

```
INSERT INTO User (col1, col2)
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: This requirement doesn't make sense at all

Comment: php has a sleep() function, so insert row, sleep, insert row...

Comment: I already tried insert row, sleep, insert row. However, in my database, it only insert the last query, not all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // da
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as $data) {
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ... SET data='".$data."'");
    sleep(1)
}
?>
```

Something like that? I did not understand very well.

Answer (score 0):

So what I do is create the query by concatenating it like this. But if you want to have multiple inserts you can call that function in a loop and remove this sleep put it in the loop outside the function or you can leave it there if the call is not a thread.

```
<?php
static function insert_table_db($anArra){
        $dbconn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die('MySQL connection failed!' . mysqli_connect_error());
        mysqli_set_charset($dbconn, "utf8");

        $query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) VALUES ";
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($anArray as $item) {
            $query = $query . "(" . $item[0]. "," . $item[1]. "," . $item[2] . "," . $item[3] . ",'" . $item[4] . "')";

            if (count($anArray) == $i){
                $query = $query . ";";
            } else {
                $query = $query . ",";
            }
            $i++;
        }

        // Run query
        if($dbconn->query($query) === true) {
            $dbconn->close();
        } else {
            echo "Database Error: " . $dbconn->error;
            $dbconn->close();
        }
    sleep(5);
}
?>
```

UPDATE: Sorry if some variables don't make sense I stripped it out of a library I have built and there are some extra things that I didn't delete ;D.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Maybe it's a bit messy but this is what I've come with and solved my problem. Basically I just need to use prepare if I want to reuse the statement.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (col1, col2) VALUES ('1','2');
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (col1, col2) VALUES ('3','4');
$stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user (col1, col2) VALUES ('5','6');

{ $stmt->execute();
  sleep(5);
  $stmt2->execute();
  sleep(5);
  $stmt3->execute();
}
```

That's all. Thanks for those who tried to solve this.